# Asp.net error creating usercontrol from WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm referencing the [article reference](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/2008/04/GridView-Grouping-Master-Detail-Drill-Down-Using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

To create a UserControl dynamically and pass it back to a page via jQuery.

When I just do a simple text in the UserControl "Hello World" everything works great... however, when I tried putting interactive controls on the control, I got the following message in my WebMethod (so the jQuery call stuff is irrelevant) (further testing showed that textboxes, and buttons cause the issue, but not labels)

Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.UI.Page'

here's the webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCtrl(string cname)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    Page p = new Page();
    Control c = p.LoadControl("~/Controls/" + cname);
    p.Controls.Add(c);

    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(p, sw, false);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        return err.Message;
    }
    sw.Close();

    return sw.ToString();
}
```

The exception is happening during the Server.Execute call.

A solution may not be possible, I'd just like to know why interactive controls cause this.

EDIT:
Taking advice below I looked deeper and found the inner exception said something to the effect that it must be within a form tag marked with runat="server", while I'm displaying this control on a aspx page within the form tag... my guess is that there's got to be some sort of 'asp.net magic' connection there for the control to operate... regardless, it'd be nice to know how to render a page with controls on it anyway (even if it wasn't usable in this situation)

So I looked at the output of the above code and for those curious:

`<span id="ctl00_lbl1">abc: </span>`

So the control is rendering properly (with just the label id='lbl1') on the page, however, the control is itself rendered, and the page content is not there at all... Is there a way to generate the page source as well? (I must not understand the way the Server.Execute function works)

Comment: Following a suggestion, I checked deeper in the debug info, and found the following inner exception:

The inner-exception was as follows (and slightly more helpful than what I had before): Control 'ctl00_btn1' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

since this is being rendered on a Page object... I wonder if there's some 'pre-work' I'd need to do to make the page a proper aspx page?... since I'm basically constructing it dynamically (we wont even talk about the improper-ness of embedding this whole thing on another page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start by narrowing down the problem. For instance, what happens if you leave off the

```
p.Controls.Add(c);
```

What happens if you properly implement a `using` statement?

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
    // ...
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(p, sw, false);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

What happens, if you leave off the try/catch? It's costing you all the information in the exception other than the Message property, so why not just leave it off? Your caller might be expecting HTML in any case, so if you keep it, you might (later) want to wrap the output:

```
return "<p>" + ex.ToString() + "</p>";
```

Little by little, remove things until the problem goes away.

---

Based on what you learned from the InnerException, I recommend that you add an HtmlForm control to the page, then add your loaded control as a child control of the HtmlForm.

Comment: using statement wouldn't help anything, as it would only give me a bit of control over the cleanup and the exception is happening in the Server.Execute function before I would even consider cleaning anything up (tested just to make sure)

The try/catch was put in so I could get live feedback of the message instead of just a blank screen, and give me a good place to do a debug break. (digging into my debug info a bit deeper was helpful)

Comment: I think that, without the try/catch, ASP.NET Health Monitoring would have logged the entire exception, including the InnerException that  you found helpful. Proper implementation of exceptions and using statements is helpful because it allows people like me to concentrate on the real problem, and not waste time being pedantic about good practice.

Answer (score 1):

[Using Scott Gu's blog as a reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx), I also came across the same problem loading server controls in my widgets (e.g. GridView and RadTreeView controls would cause the same error) for our company's dashboard. Following John Saunders's tip, I added an HTML form control and script manager control (for RadTreeView controls) and it fixed the problem. Now my user controls render out as pure HTML. w00t!

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] LoadWidget(string widgetID, string widgetPath)
{
    try
    {
        var pageHolder = new Page();
        var form = new HtmlForm();
        var viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(widgetPath);
        var scriptManager = new ScriptManager();
        form.Controls.Add(scriptManager);
        form.Controls.Add(viewControl);
        pageHolder.Controls.Add(form);

        var output = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);

        return new string[]
        {
            widgetID, output.ToString()
        };
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle error...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try rendering the control and sending that string back...

```
Control ctrl;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: @George, would you also implement using statements, considering most of those objects you're creating implement IDisposable?

Comment: Good idea using the RenderControl method, unfortunately this doesn't cause the control to go through a page lifecycle (so the Page_Load event for instance, doesn't get called)

Comment: The control has it's own lifecycle it will go through.  If you had code in the Page the object is contained in move it to the Load event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775(VS.71).aspx